# How can I test if a curried axios action was called?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, jestjs

I have a following action, it's an axios call with curried dispatch.

Note: originally, we wouldn't need to curry the action call like that, but let's say there is a situation where I need to make it curried (code below is just a made-up example).

./src/store/Auth/auth.action.ts

```
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    getUsersData: () => (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
        return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((result) => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'SET_USERS',
                payload: result
            });

            return result;
        })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.error(e);
            });
    },
}
```

./src/screens/Testing/index.tsx

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import Action from '../../store/Auth/auth.action';

const useAppDispatch = (action: any) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return useCallback((param?: any, callback?: any) => dispatch(action(param, callback)), [dispatch, action]);
};

const Testing = () => {
    const getUsersDataAction = useAppDispatch(Action.getUsersData);

    return (
        <View>
            <Button
                title='hit me'
                testID='hit_me_id'
                onPress={ () => getUsersDataAction() }
            />
        </View>
    );
};

export default Testing;
```

action.test.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactRedux from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react-native';

import { Testing } from '../../src/screens';

describe('Get users data', () => {
    it('should return correct payload', async () => {
        const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

        jest.spyOn(ReactRedux, 'useDispatch').mockReturnValue(mockDispatch);

        axios.get.mockResolvedValue({});

        const screen = render(
            <Testing />
        );

        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(screen.getByTestId('hit_me_id')).toBeTruthy();
        });

        await waitFor(() => {
            fireEvent.press(screen.getByTestId('hit_me_id'));
        });

        expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    });
});
```

I got a following result:
[image]

Expected result is:
[image]

I feel the mock declaration is still not right.

```
const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

jest.spyOn(ReactRedux, 'useDispatch').mockReturnValue(mockDispatch);
```

Have tried with some other ways like:

```
const mockDispatch = () => jest.fn();
const mockDispatch = jest.fn(() => () => null);

jest.spyOn(ReactRedux, 'useDispatch').mockReturnValue(mockDispatch();
jest.spyOn(ReactRedux, 'useDispatch').mockReturnValue(() => mockDispatch();
```

but still not found the solution.

Does anyone know how to mock a curried function with Jest?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't used Redux for a long time, so my insight about the Redux part might not be 100% accurate regarding the part of calling actions / action creators.

## The solution to the question

It seems that the missing part is mocking the behaviour of your `mockDispatch` function.

**TL;DR:** Mock your `mockDispatch` implementation so it calls the `getUsersData` function from your actions.

**Explanation:**

This is what your code does:

1. You obtain a `getUsersDataAction` function with your
   `useAppDispatch` hook. This returns a function that will be called
   on press.
2. Press event happens. `getUsersDataAction` is called.
3. You get the `dispatch` function by calling `useDispatch`.
4. The `dispatch` function is called with your action, what does whatever it has to do (calling `axios` in this case).

This is what your test code does:

1. Press event happens. `getUsersDataAction` is called.
2. Given `useDispatch` is called but you've mocked its return value, `mockDispatch` is returned.
3. `mockDispatch` is called. `mockDispatch` is just `jest.fn()`; no mock resolved values or mock implementations have been defined for it (or not an implementation that does anything in particular in your later approaches), so nothing is actually done in this call.
4. The actual `getUsersData` from your actions file (the one who actually calls `axios`) is never run because nothing calls it.

My suggestion is to mock the implementation of `mockDispatch` in a way that actually calls your action:

```js
const mockDispatch = jest.fn(() => Action.getUsersData()(jest.fn())) // Another jest.fn just because your action expects a dispatch argument.
```

## My approach as an engineer

Don't test everything as a whole. You can assume that Redux is a well tested library, so call the parts actually done by you in a separate way:

- Test your view until the Redux part comes in (in your case, until `mockDispatch` is called).
- Test your action separately with unit tests in order to make sure axios is called the way you expect.
- The in-between part is Redux's job. Redux is well maintained and we should safely assume it works right.

I understand you can be interested in a more integrated approach that proves both, but I'd leave that for an e2e test. Integration tests made with tools more focused on unit tests (what is Jest's case) that also selectively mocks in-between stuff are harder to reason about. If a test is going to be expensive to read and maintain, let better make it an e2e test.

Comment: This is a thorough and detailed answer and it solved the problem. Thank you. I get your point, testing everything as a whole in a single run might make the test seems too complicated and hard to debug. Separate it to become an individual unit test is a better approach. Noted on that.

Comment: I missed the step to mock the mockDispatch in a way that actually calls the action. Because if I remove the curried function and make the action to be just `getUsersData: () => {...}`, the test run successfully with only `const mockDispatch = jest.fn();`.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you to spy the axios request too in this way:

```
const axiosSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get')
axiosSpy.mockReturnValue({})
expect(axiosSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
```

Then, since is the `toHaveBeenCalledWith` function that is failing, meaning that `expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` is passing, the expectation here is that the arguments are not resolved (called) since we are using a mocked function for `dispatch` .

In this scenario I suggest you to mock the implementation of `dispatch` to call the action:

```
mockDispatch.mockImplementation((action) => action()) //Add correct arguments
```

Comment: Try to debug the execution of the test to see what's going on

Comment: Btw which arguments do you mean to add there? the action is an api GET, so it has no arguments.

Comment: No, I see you are passing some parameters in the code you put above but I don't know how they work

Comment: I see, I understand your point about mocking the axios, but I don't know how to mock the implementation of dispatch in the correct way, as you hinted above. Appreciate your thoughts there. Thanks Andrea.